# JQuery Ajax error with XHR status is 0; means not connected

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have following snippet of code

```
   $.ajax({
            method  :   "GET",
            url     :   'http://projectstorehouse.com/travelnews/index.html',
            data    :   "",
            success :   function(){
                            alert("Hello");
                        },
            error   :   function(jqXHR, status, error){
                        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                            alert('Not connected.\nPlease verify your network connection.');
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                            alert ('The requested page not found. [404]');
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                            alert ('Internal Server Error [500].');
                        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                            alert ('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                            alert ('Time out error.');
                        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                            alert ('Ajax request aborted.');
                        } else {
                            alert ('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                        }
            }
        });
```

and could not figure out problem associated with it; the message displayed with this is jqXHR.status==0. Url is reachable http://projectstorehouse.com/travelnews/index.html

Can anybody tell me where I am wrong;

Comment: Check your browser console to see the error.... you might have a message like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://projectstorehouse.com/travelnews/index.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: thanks, unfortunately  no error in console regarding this.

Comment: Yeah, getting exactly same error with no good reason.  In fact, it seems the code is executing OK, except for the error return.