# PHP AJAX MYSQL Post Data is not being recieved

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

So I'm trying to post/update data in a MySQL table but it seems like the post data is not being received. I need help getting the POST data to output.

users.php

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="" >
    <input hidden name="identifier" id="identifier" value="<?php echo $identifier; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" id="sub" class="btn btn-info pull-right"/>
</form>
```

actions/users_manage.php

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_name', 'db_user', 'db_pass');
$identifier = htmlspecialchars($_POST['identifier']);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET identifier=:identifier WHERE identifier=:identifier");
    $stmt->execute([':identifier' => $identifier]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
die();
}
```

actions/users_manage.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "actions/users_manage.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function( data )
        {
            alert( data );
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error');
        }
    });

    return false;
    });
});
```

When I try adding a var_dump($_POST) into the users_manage.php above the if(isset) it displays array(0){}, so the processing is working. It's just not receiving any POST data, please help :) Thanks greatly appreciated!

When I add this to the users_manage.php:

```
var_dump($_POST['identifier']);
```

It displays the alert with "NULL".

Comment: Try to `alert` post `$(this).serialize()` check what exactly it is.

Comment: @Reno I already am doing that aren't I? If not please explain thanks

Comment: @Reno All it is doing, is alerting with no message (just blank).
`success: function()
            {
                alert( $(this).serialize() );
            }`

Comment: So `$(this).serialize()` get you blank value?

Comment: `success: function()
            {
                alert( $(this).serialize() );
            }` gives me blank

Comment: Do this `alert` before you send ajax request please.

Comment: okay so it's outputting the data, now how do I get it working :D

Comment: What is content of data?

Comment: It's in the format: `identifier=907892442`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113975/discussion-between-harvey-connor-and-reno).

Comment: look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649653/jquery-ajax-error-with-xhr-status-is-0-means-not-connected, can you comment what happened after using this in your error function,

Comment: it just returns as a success

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, I needed to change the `var data = $(this).serialize();` to var `data = $(this).serialize();` it manages to work.

Working ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    data = $(this).serialize();
    // alert(data);
    $.ajax({
        url: "actions/users_manage",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success :   function(){
            alert(data);
        },
        error   :   function(){
            alert('Error');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
});
```